# is there a way to add an incrementing index to group_concat column?

Tags: mysql

I need to have an incrementing index number for each row inside the group concat column. is that possible by any means?

```
SELECT pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT(CATE_ID SEPARATOR '/')
 FROM book_mast
 GROUP BY pub_id;
```

instead of

```
| P001   | CA002/CA004
| P002   | CA003
```

I want

```
| P001   | 1-CA002/2-CA004
| P002   | 1-CA003
```

is there any way of doing this?

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: Is there any column can represent the order?

Comment: mysql version is 5.7.12

Comment: "Is there any column can represent the order?"
I don't understand the question

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a variable and increment it:

```
SET @a:=0;
SELECT cate_ids FROM ( 
    SELECT @a:=0, pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( @a:=@a+1, '-', CATE_ID ) SEPARATOR '/') as cate_ids
    FROM book_mast
    GROUP BY pub_id 
);
```

You need to create a variable and on each selection set it to 0 and increment it on the group_concat function in order to count the results of the group concat of each row and not the rows itselfs.

Also I use a subselect in order to get rid of the 0 field created by the setting of @a.

Comment: this returned 

| P001   | 1-CA002/2-CA004

| P002   | 3-CA003

and it keeps incrementing instead of returning to 0 on each row

Comment: @BillNewton Check it now, I was editing it in order to fit the request more precisely.